# Ruby Simple Read/Write File (Copy File)

Tags: ruby

I am practicing Ruby, and I am trying to copy contents from file "from" to file "to". can you tell me where I did it wrong?

thanks !

```
from = "1.txt"
to = "2.txt"
data = open(from).read
out = open(to, 'w')
out.write(data)
out.close
data.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing the point, but I think writing it like so is more 'ruby'

```
from = "1.txt"
to = "2.txt"
contents = File.open(from, 'r').read
File.open(to, 'w').write(contents)
```

Personally, however, I like to use the Operating systems terminal to do File operations like so. Here is an example on linux.

```
from = "1.txt"
to = "2.txt"
system("cp #{from} #{to}")
```

And for Windows I believe you would use..

```
from = "1.txt"
to = "2.txt"
system("copy #{from} #{to}")
```

Finally, if you were needing the output of the command for some sort of logging or other reason, I would use backticks.

```
#A nice one liner
`cp 1.txt 2.txt`
```

Here is the system and backtick methods documentation. 
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html

Comment: thanks, Schylar, I like the 'ruby' thinking way. hah

Comment: I have a couple of problems with the approaches you advocate.  In the first case, you're not closing the files.  That's a bad practice to get into.  With your use of `system` or backticks, you have introduced a system dependency and made the solution non-portable.  Keeping it all internal to Ruby is a portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform `data.close` — `data.class` would show you that you have a `String`, and `.close` is not a valid `String` method.  By opening `from` the way you chose to, you lost the `File` reference after using it with your `read`.  One way to fix that would be:

```
from = "1.txt"
to = "2.txt"
infile = open(from)  # Retain the File reference
data = infile.read   # Use it to do the read
out = open(to, 'w')
out.write(data)
out.close
infile.close         # And finally, close it
```